# How to disable only a input field with checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, clone, disable

I would like to disable the "Date of Completion" field with the checkbox.

The problem is that I created these fields dynamically, so when I try to disable only the field relating to it, it disables all other "Date of Completion" fields I would like to disable only the previous field and not all others.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyrTq.gif)

```
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)    
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
        { 
            startDate: "Start Date",            
            completionDate: "Completion Date:",
            inline: true 
        }
    ])
    const handleInputChange = (e, index, val) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setChecked(e.target.checked)    
    
        const list = [...inputList]
    
        list[index][name] = val !== undefined ? val : value 
        setInputList(list)
    }
    const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
        const list = [...inputList]
        list.splice(index, 1)
        setInputList(list)
    }
    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setInputList([
            ...inputList,
            { 
                startDate: "Start Date",            
                completionDate: "Completion Date:",
                inline: true 
            }
        ])
    }
    let embed = {
        embed: {
            fields: inputList
        }
    }    
    //Form
    {inputList.map((x, i) => {                
        return (
            <>           
                <FormControl>
                    <Box>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor='startDate'>Start Date:</FormLabel>                      
                        <Input 
                            name="startDate"
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}              
                            type='text' 
                            placeholder='Start Date' 
                        />                                                
                    </Box>
                    <Box>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor='completionDate'>Completion Date:</FormLabel>                        
                        <Input 
                            name="completionDate"
                            isDisabled={checked ? true : false}
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)} 
                            type='text' 
                            placeholder='Completion Date' 
                        />                                                
                    </Box>                
                    <Box pt={{ base: '0', md: '2.7rem'}}>                       
                        <Checkbox  
                            type="checkbox" 
                            name="inline" 
                            checked={x.inline}                                     
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i, e.target.checked)}
                            colorScheme='purple'>
                                <label>Studying</label>
                        </Checkbox>  
                    </Box>                                 
                </FormControl>           
                {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                    <Button onClick={handleAddClick}> + New Section </Button> 
                    )}
                {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                    <Button  onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>- Remove Section</Button> 
                )}                      
              
            </>
        )
    })}
```

Comment: can you create a working snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `checked` to `inputList` object.

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    {
        startDate: "Start Date",
        completionDate: "Completion Date:",
        inline: true,
        checked: false
    }
])
const handleInputChange = (e, index, val) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target

    let newList = inputList
    newList[index]['checked'] = e.target.checked
    setInputList(newList)

    const list = [...inputList]

    list[index][name] = val !== undefined ? val : value
    setInputList(list)
}
const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList]
    list.splice(index, 1)
    setInputList(list)
}
const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([
        ...inputList,
        {
            startDate: "Start Date",
            completionDate: "Completion Date:",
            inline: true,
            checked: false
        }
    ])
}
let embed = {
    embed: {
        fields: inputList
    }
}
//Form
{
    inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
            <>
                <FormControl>
                    <Box>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor='startDate'>Start Date:</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name="startDate"
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='Start Date'
                        />
                    </Box>
                    <Box>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor='completionDate'>Completion Date:</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            name="completionDate"
                            isDisabled={x.checked}
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                            type='text'
                            placeholder='Completion Date'
                        />
                    </Box>
                    <Box pt={{ base: '0', md: '2.7rem' }}>
                        <Checkbox
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="inline"
                            checked={x.inline}
                            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i, e.target.checked)}
                            colorScheme='purple'>
                            <label>Studying</label>
                        </Checkbox>
                    </Box>
                </FormControl>
                {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                    <Button onClick={handleAddClick}> + New Section </Button>
                )}
                {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                    <Button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>- Remove Section</Button>
                )}

            </>
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your completion date input `isDisabled` property depends on one `checked` state which is shared with all completion date input.

```js
<Input 
    name="completionDate"
    isDisabled={checked ? true : false}       //  <--- checked shared state
    ...
/>
```

So, when you click any checkbox, the checked state will be updated by `handleInputChange` and all completion date input will be in disabled/enabled mode, depending on the latest clicked checkbox checked value.

As said by [@hossein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72876380/8198873), you need to add `checked` property. So, let's do it.

First, update your `inputList` initialization:

```js
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    {
      startDate: undefined,           // to hold startDate value
      completionDate: undefined,      // to hold completionDate value
      disabled: false,                // to hold completionDate disabled state
      checked: false,                 // to hold inline checked state
    },
  ]);
```

Next, update your `handleInputChange` method:

```js
  const handleInputChange = (e, i) => {
    const { checked, name, value } = e.target;
    setInputList((prevState) => {
      if (name === "inline") {
        prevState[i].checked = checked;
        prevState[i].disabled = checked;  // disabled value follows checked value
      } else {
        prevState[i][name] = value;
      }
      return [...prevState];
    });
  };
```

Next, update your handleAddClick method:

```js
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList((prevState) => {
      const newInputs = {
        startDate: undefined,
        completionDate: undefined,
        disabled: false,
        checked: false,
      };
      return [...prevState, newInputs];
    });
  };
```

And finally, update your `onChange` at Checkbox component:

```js
// from
onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i, e.target.checked)}
// into
onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
```

Your code should work after you made those updates.

Here is the minimal example that works:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
        {
        startDate: undefined,
        completionDate: undefined,
        disabled: false,
        checked: false,
        },
    ]);

    const handleInputChange = (e, i) => {
        const { checked, name, value } = e.target;
        setInputList((prevState) => {
        if (name === "inline") {
            prevState[i].checked = checked;
            prevState[i].disabled = checked;
        } else {
            prevState[i][name] = value;
        }
        return [...prevState];
        });
    };

    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setInputList((prevState) => {
        const newInputs = {
            startDate: undefined,
            completionDate: undefined,
            disabled: false,
            checked: false,
        };
        return [...prevState, newInputs];
        });
    };

    const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
        const list = [...inputList];
        list.splice(index, 1);
        setInputList(list);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>App</div>
            {inputList.map((input, i) => {
                return (
                <div key={i}>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                    <label>
                        Start Date:
                        <input
                        name="startDate"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                        placeholder="Start Date"
                        />
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label>
                        Completion Date:
                        <input
                        name="completionDate"
                        type="text"
                        disabled={input.disabled}
                        onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                        placeholder="Completion Date"
                        />
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label htmlFor={`checkbox-${i}`} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                        <input
                        id={`checkbox-${i}`}
                        name="inline"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={input.checked}
                        onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                        />
                        {`Checkbox-${i}`}
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                    <button onClick={() => handleAddClick()}>+ New Section</button>
                    )}
                    {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}>
                            - Remove Section
                        </button>
                    )}
                </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you you saved my life :) I've been trying to do this for days and I didn't know how. Really thank you very much.